# Visual basic. Change default startup form in code, depending on value of variable

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2013

I have been working on a Visual Basic project in Visual Studio and have encountered a problem.

I understand that the Startup form property in the Application page of the Project Designer can be changed to a default form, however what I require is a way to do this through code in ApplicationEvents.vb depending on the value of a variable within application settings.

The goal is that if a user completes a form then a value is assigned to a variable, e.g. variable username = "xxx". If this value is true, then the default startup is a login form (as the user has already registered), and if it is false then the user is taken to a register form.

I appreciate that I could use another form to determine this, however this seems like I would be squandering the capabilities of ApplicationEvents and not using it correctly (I also want to avoid the inevitable flicker of a blank form as it decides).

I know that the default form is stored in Application.myapp, however with the final publication of the .exe this file will (presumably) not be exported with it, so I want to avoid writing directly to it. I have also read into the windowsformsapplicationbase.mainform property, however cannot figure out how to use it?

Here is a example piece of code from ApplicationEvents.vb to demonstrate my question.

```
 If String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.username) Then
     MsgBox("You have not registered")
     'set register as default form
 Else
     MsgBox("You have registered")
     'set login as default form
 End If
```

Comment: Your app can also start from a `Sub Main` in a Module.  There you could decide which form to start with.  You should know that NET includes a `LicenseManager` framework which might work better than storing a value in an XML file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, if you need that much control over what happens at start-up, you just want to disable the a application framework.  To do so, just un-check the **Enable application framework** check-box in the **Application** tab of the **My Project** settings designer window.  Once you un-check that, you will be able to change the **Startup object** to **Sub Main**.  Then you can add a new module with a `Main` method, like this:

```
Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.username) Then
            Application.Run(New RegisterForm())
        Else
            Application.Run(New LoginForm())
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Be aware, however--by disabling the application framework, you will loose the other automatic functionality that it provides, such as `ApplicationEvents`.  If you want to use the application framework, you can accomplish the same thing by simply setting the `MyApplication.MainForm` property in the `MyApplication.Startup` event:

```
Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.username) Then
            Me.MainForm = New RegisterForm()
        Else
            Me.MainForm = New LoginForm()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Alternatively, you could always show the same form, but then have the form contain nothing but a single `UserControl`.  Then you can simply switch which `UserControl` is displayed depending upon the settings.  The user-controls would need to include all of the controls that would have otherwise been placed on the two different forms.

Comment: Quick response, in depth, and spot on. Thank you very much.